# Showing that a function is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, integration, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I have a function $H$ whose domain is the set $C$ of the continuous functions $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. $H$ is defined by $$H(f)(t) := \int_0^t \phi(f(s))ds $$ for $t \in [0,1], f \in C$ and with $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ continuous.

What would be a nontrivial condition (imposed onto $\phi$) under which $H$ is a contraction? I know I have to show for $f,g \in C$
 that $$d_{sup} (H(f), H(g))= \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \left|\int_0^t \phi(f(s)) - \phi(g(s))ds\right| \leq L \sup_{t \in [0,1]} {|f(t)-g(t)|} = L d_{sup}(f,g)$$ with $L<1$. But all I arrive at is $$d_{sup}(H(f), H(g)) \leq M-m$$ where $M, m$ denote the maximum of $\phi \circ f$/minimum of $\phi \circ g$ which both exist by the properties of continuous functions on 
compact intervalls. What am I missing here?

Also is it correct that $H$ maps to itself, i.e. that $H(f)$ is continuous? Thanks!

Comment: Are you integrating with respect to $s$ or $x$?

Comment: To obtain the "I know I have to show" condition you should impose the Lipschitz condition on $\phi$ with Lipschitz constant $L < 1$.

Comment: To answer your last question, note that every continuous function is Riemann-integrable, and the composition of a continuous function with a Riemann-integrable function is itself Riemann-integrable (on $[0,1]$, in this case). Hence, $H(t)$ as defined will be continuous on $[0,1]$. (For a proof, see Theorem 6.20 of Rudin's PMA).

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thanks, that does the job. Is this the only condition that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supone $\phi$ is Lipschitz with constant $L_\phi$. Then, for any $f,g\in C[0,1]$
\begin{align}
|H(f)(t)-H(g)(t)|&\le\int_0^t|\phi(f(s))-\phi(g(s))|\,ds\\
&\le L_\phi\int_0^t|f(s)-g(s)|\,ds\\
&\le L_\phi\,d_{\text{sup}}(f,g),
\end{align}
and
$$
d_{\text{sup}}(H(f),H(g))\le L_\phi\,d_{\text{sup}}(f,g).
$$